# Heroku's Windows toolbelt and LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: php, heroku, command-line-interface

I'm deploying a PHP application on Heroku and I need to run some tasks using CLI.
In order to do that I have to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable using this command:
`heroku config:add LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/php/ext:/app/apache/lib`
but every time I do it toolbelt overrides the command and the variable points to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\app\php\ext;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\app\apache\lib`. Obviously it's not okay. Does anyone have any ideas how to do this in proper way?

Answer (score 1):

5 days passed and still I have no answer. The CLI interface is used by scheduler, so I could use this workaround:

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/php/ext:/app/apache/lib && ~/bin/php ~/www/index.php cron

Answer (score 1):

This is actually not a problem with Heroku toolbelt, it's [documented behavior by msys](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion) (I'm assuming you're running this in the msysgit shell). You can either run the command in a different shell (eg. Powershell) or use '//' at the start of the path like this:

```
heroku config:add LD_LIBRARY_PATH=//app/php/ext://app/apache/lib
```

This won't cause  problems when the path is used on Linux.